# MongoDB error "can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this code:

```
db.Vehicles.ensureIndex({"location":"2dsphere"});

db.vehicles.find({
    "location": {
    $near: {
        $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [32.081473, 32.081473]
        },
        $maxDistance: 5000
    }
    }
})
```

My location is:

```
location":{"type":"point", "coordinates": ["32.081473", "32.08473"]}
```

I am getting an error:

```
err: can't extract gel keys from object, malformed geometry?
```

I have seen some problems that looks like mine, but their solutions was adding the ensureIndex which I have added already.

Comment: can u please check your coordinates? It is string, and should be number format.

Comment: how are you inserting `location` data ?

Comment: @chridam why? I tried but still same error   -Vishwas- I tried that also still same error. -dev - I wrote it in the question. I'm using robomongo

Answer (score 0):

We can see that your coordinates are Strings: `["32.081473", "32.08473"]`
whereas they should be numbers. In the schema definition, the coordinates must be defined as an array of Numbers:

```
var VehicleSchema = new Schema({
  loc: {
    type: {
      type: String
    },
    coordinates: [Number]
  },
});
```